# How can i make search icon clickable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

```
<div data-role=page">
    <form method="post">
        <input name="search" id="search" value="" placeholder="Buscar" type="search" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Buscar'">
    </form>
</div>
```

I am using jquery mobiles 1.4.2 How can i make search icon clickable(like a enter)when we click on it it should act like a enter button. 
And how can i change the border color of it?

Comment: can you show html with ICON

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are trying to do. In your code I don't see a search icon. But if there would be one you could try to bind a click and touchend event. But if it's not about mobile touch devices but "act like a enter button" then you would need a keyup event for the enter button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set here border please look at this.

```
<div data-role=page">
<form method="post">
<input style='border:1px solid red;' name="search" id="search" value=""  placeholder="Buscar" type="search" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Buscar'">
</form>
</div>
```

Look at this thread

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/anyone-have-a-way-to-bind-to-clicks-of-the-magnifying-glass-on-the-search-box

Comment: when we use jquery mobile it will add aromatically search icon

Answer (score 0):

The search icon in jQuery Mobile is implemented in a pseudo :after element. This means that as far as jQuery/JavaScript is concerned it is not part of the DOM and you cannot attach events to it.

As a workaround, you can insert an invisible DOM element (e.g. SPAN) on top of the icon and add a click event to that element:

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="search" id="search" value="" placeholder="Buscar" type="search" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Buscar'" />
</form>
```

So given the above markup, the following code will insert a SPAN and add a click event handler:

```
var s = '<span class="fakeSearchButton"></span>';
$("#search").parents(".ui-input-search").append(s);

$(document).on("click", ".fakeSearchButton", function(){
    alert("search icon click");
});
```

Then to place the SPAN correctly add this CSS:

```
.fakeSearchButton{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 14px;
    left: 0.3215em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -7px;
    width: 14px;
    z-index: 200;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5W76X/1/)**

To change the border color and inset shadowing of the search input, use the following CSS:

```
.ui-input-search {
  border-color: #7FAF1B !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow:rgb(217,255,169) 0px 1px 2px 0px inset;
  box-shadow:rgb(217,255,169) 0px 1px 2px 0px inset;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5W76X/3/)**